# Xml Encryption/Decryption without session

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I write some code to encrypt/decrpyt xml files and when I run the encryption and decryption together on my local machine it throw CryptographicException "Unabled to retrive the descryption key" and I don't get it why.However decryption must working on two different machines.

Can someone help me ?

Here is my code to Encrypt xml

```
          private static void EncryptXML(XmlDocument Xml, string EncryptElement, string KeyName)
         {
        if (Xml == null || EncryptElement == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var cspParams = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = "XML_RSA_FTP_KEY" };

        var rsaAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        XmlElement element = Xml.GetElementsByTagName(EncryptElement)[0] as XmlElement;

        try
        {
            RijndaelManaged SKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            SKey.KeySize = 256;

            EncryptedXml encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml();
            byte[] encryptedElement = encryptedXml.EncryptData(element, SKey, false);

            EncryptedData ElementData = new EncryptedData();
            ElementData.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;

            ElementData.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);
            EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();

            byte[] KeyToEncrypt = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(SKey.Key, rsaAlg, false);

            ek.CipherData = new CipherData(KeyToEncrypt);
            ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

            DataReference dRef = new DataReference();
            dRef.Uri = "#" + 2;

            ek.AddReference(dRef);

            ElementData.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));

            var property = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("EncryptionProperty", EncryptedXml.XmlEncNamespaceUrl);

            property.InnerText = RijndaelManagedEncryption.EncryptRijndael(Convert.ToBase64String(rsaAlg.ExportCspBlob(true)), "SaltMordo");

            var encProperty = new EncryptionProperty(property);

            ek.AddProperty(encProperty);

            KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();

            ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);

            ElementData.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;

            EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(element, ElementData, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Here is decrypt

```
     private static void DecryptXML(XmlDocument Xml, RSA key, string KeyName)
    {
        if (Xml == null || key == null || KeyName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = Xml;

        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_RSA_FTP_KEY";
        cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

        RSACryptoServiceProvider ftpkey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        var KeyInfo = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EncryptionProperty")[0].InnerText;
        ftpkey.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(RijndaelManagedEncryption.DecryptRijndael(KeyInfo,
            "SaltMordo")));


        EncryptedXml encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);
        encryptedXml.AddKeyNameMapping("ftpkey", ftpkey);
        encryptedXml.DecryptDocument();
    }
```

And Rijndael Class

```
    public class RijndaelManagedEncryption
{
    #region Consts
    /// <summary>
    /// Change the Inputkey GUID when you use this code in your own program.
    /// Keep this inputkey very safe and prevent someone from decoding it some way!!
    /// </summary>
    internal const string Inputkey = "560A18CD-6346-4CF0-A2E8-671F9B6B9EA9";
    #endregion

    #region Rijndael Encryption

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt the given text and give the byte array back as a BASE64 string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text" />The text to encrypt
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns>The encrypted text</returns>
    public static string EncryptRijndael(string text, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);

        var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            swEncrypt.Write(text);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a string is base64 encoded
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="base64String" />The base64 encoded string
    /// <returns>Base64 encoded stringt</returns>
    public static bool IsBase64String(string base64String)
    {
        base64String = base64String.Trim();
        return (base64String.Length % 4 == 0) &&
               Regex.IsMatch(base64String, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts the given text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText" />The encrypted BASE64 text
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns>The decrypted text</returns>
    public static string DecryptRijndael(string cipherText, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

        if (!IsBase64String(cipherText))
            throw new Exception("The cipherText input parameter is not base64 encoded");

        string text;

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);
        var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
    #endregion

    #region NewRijndaelManaged
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new RijndaelManaged class and initialize it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static RijndaelManaged NewRijndaelManaged(string salt)
    {
        if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
        var saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Inputkey, saltBytes);

        var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
        aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);

        return aesAlg;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have the same version of Net Library on all machines and the same version of windows.

Comment: I got same versions

Comment: Are you mixing XML encryption (the standard) with your own encryption scheme by just replacing the ciphertext? Or am I misreading your code?

Comment: Same project settings X86, X64?  All Net Library updates?  Are you deploying or building on each machine?  Make sure you do clean build and running same date/time executable.

Comment: Everything is same, and I don't get it why its not working becouse if I use it on local machine this throw cryptographicexception

Comment: @jdweng do you have any idea how can I repair this ?

Comment: I don't think you are storing the key so when you try to get key it fails at : CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore  Find out what instruction is failing and make sure the inputs are not null.  I prefer a try/catch instead of the using statements. Have seen issue where the using masks exceptions.